# Inaccuracies with decimals in Python

Tags: python, decimal

The following simple code:

```
from decimal import getcontext
from decimal import *
import math

context = getcontext()
context.prec = 300    

def f(x):
    return Decimal(math.atan(10**(-x+1)))

def xNext(x,y):
    return x-y*f(2)


def yNext(x,y):
    return y+x*f(2)

x= Decimal(1)
y = Decimal(0)

x=xNext(x,y)
y=yNext(x,y)

x=xNext(x,y)
y=yNext(x,y)

x=xNext(x,y)
y=yNext(x,y)

print("{:.16f}".format(x))
print("{:.16f}".format(y))
```

returns

```
0.9702971603146833
0.2950554229911823
```

Which is wrong, should be around 0.97019857 and 0.2980158649
I thought this was a rounding error but this code should be working to 300 decimal places.

Not sure if different problem or not really going to 300 places...

EDIT: Yeah, I doubt it's a rounding error, I've just done the same process on wolfram only to around 20 decimal places at a time and my answer's more accurate than this one.

Comment: I just tried to execute the code snippet, but it doesn't work for me. Error Message is `ValueError: zero length field name in format` in the pre-last line. Executing with Ipython and Python 2.6.8...

Comment: @WWhisperer add  `0`  `{0:.16f}` to your formatting

Comment: @WWhisperer: That print format needs Python 2.7 or better. But Padraic shows how to make it compatible to Python 2.6 and later.

Comment: The `math` module doesn't magically inherit `decimal`'s precision. If you want to do arbitrary precision mathematics with all sorts of fancy functions, check out [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/)

Comment: alright, thank you. I already thought that the problem would be in the `f(x)` function as Tony says in his answer... Just wanted to make sure I am not posting an unresearched answer.

Comment: FWIW, the values I get for x & y to 30 places using mpmath with 100 digits of precision are  0.970297160314683330698032087931 and
0.295055422991182245000100661959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal doesn't extend your precision, because you use the `math` module. But that's not the point. Are you sure you calculation is correct? Just tried:

```
x, y = 1, 0
x, y = xNext(x,y), yNext(x,y)
x, y = xNext(x,y), yNext(x,y)
x, y = xNext(x,y), yNext(x,y)
```

And it leads to

```
0.970198479132
0.298015864998
```

which is basically your expected result.

Comment: Hey, that is! Sorry, yeah working mainly by hand. Any idea why that works when mine doesn't? They look functionally the same to me...

Comment: The version by @Daniel calculates xNext and yNext using the same values of x and y, and then updates both variables at the same time. In your code, yNext is calculated from an updated version of x and not the original x.

Comment: @user2998454: FWIW, using mpmath on this algorithm I get 0.970198479131787944181898676847 & 0.298015864997778768581294686561; only 30 digits of precision (`mp.dps=30`) were required, higher precision settings make no difference here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies here :

```
 return Decimal(math.atan(10**(-x+1)))
```

I would imagine that ALL of the calculations in that formula (especially the math.atan function) will be calculated as a normal precision floating point number - and then converted back to a 300 decimal point Decimal.

If you want 300 point precision, you MUST find a way to ensure that every calculation is executed to that level of precision or better, as your result will only be as precise as your LEAST precise calculation.

Comment: But my calculator (CAS) does it with only around 16 decimal places, also my error is only around the 3rd or forth decimal places and I've had more complicated functions with more square roots and iterations work to a far greater accuracy.

Comment: As Daniel has pointed out you had functional issues in your code anyway, but my basic point remains valid - you can't carry out calculations with 16 decimal point precission and then suddenly expect a result with 300 decimal point precision - if all of your values are 16 points at best, and the calculations are 16 point at best, then the most accurate your result will be is 15 point. It is impossible to suddenly create the other 285 decimal points of information if they aren't there already.